# Solving the IVP for Heat Equation in Three Dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the following Initial Value Problem:

$$ ∂_t f(x,t)−∆f(x,t) = 0 \hspace{.3 cm} x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \hspace{.3 cm}0< t $$

$$ f(x,0) = \exp(-|x|^2) \hspace{.3 cm} x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \hspace{.3 cm} t= 0 $$

I have already managed to prove that $$ f(x,t) = \phi \ast f(x,0) $$

but I just cannot seem to integrate the final solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $\phi$? And is $\ast$ supposed to signify convolution?

Comment: @K.defaoite, Right, the $$\phi$$ is supposed to signify the Fundamental Solution, and $$\ast$$ is the convolution operator.

Comment: The convolution form is valid and perfectly acceptable solution. Computing the convolution is very difficult in general. What is the fundamental solution that you calculated?

Comment: Please excuse my questions, but can you elaborate on the "fundamental solution"? I might know it by different terminology...

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks again for your help y'all. So for the brevity of this problem, lets assume the fundamental Solution is given, namely its the following; $$ \phi(x) = \frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^(3/2)} \exp(-x^2/4t) $$

Comment: @AndrewShedlock thanks for asking, I've commented above.

Comment: @BrazyOski Yep, just found it on wiki. The point source solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental solution
$\phi(x,t) = (4 \pi t)^{-3/2} \exp(-|x|^2/4t)$
solves the heat equation with a dirac delta as initial data. But the heat equation is autonomous in $t$, so this means that $\phi(x,1+t)$ solves the PDE with $\phi(x,1)$ as the initial data. Since the heat equation is linear, and
$$ \exp(-|x|^2) = (4\pi)^{3/2} \phi(x,1),$$
the solution (unique in various senses eg in $L^2$) to your IVP is $u(x,t) = (4\pi)^{3/2} \phi(x,1+t)$.

By the way, the set of gaussians is invariant under convolution. You should be able to show this by completing the square in the exponential. Another way to see this is to use the Fourier transform- note that writing $E_a(x):=\exp(-a|x|^2)$, we have (since $\mathcal F E_a = C E_{a'}$ for some constants $a',C$ depending on your convention for the Fourier transform
$$ E_a * E_b (x) = \mathcal F^{-1}(C'E_{a'}E_{b'})(x) = \mathcal F^{-1}(C'E_{a'+b'})(x) = C''E_c(x) $$
for some other constants $c,C',C''$. I'll leave the details to you.